# C# Cannot Load ActiveDirectory Module for Powershell Remote Use

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory, remote-access

I'm trying to execute some very simple Powershell/ActiveDirectory cmdlts, remotely, but I cannot get the ActiveDirectory module to load. I've tried a couple different things, including registering a remote shell on the remote server that loads the module, but I can't get that to work either.

**What works:** The remote setup works. My C# code can connect to the remote machine and execute Exchange commands, like **New-Mailbox**. However, I cannot execute commands like **Add-ADGroupMember**.

If I login to the remote machine I can verify all the Powershell cmdlts are available, for *both Exchange and AD*. So I know they work on the remote machine if I just login to Powershell.

Attempting to execute **Add-ADGroupMember** gives me the error that it is not recognized as a cmdlet. This indicates, to me, that the ActiveDirectory module is not loaded. However, if I try to import it, like so:

```
ps.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("ActiveDirectory");
```

this command fails with the error that the term 'Import-Module' is also not a recognized cmdlet.

I have also tried connecting to a shellURI that specifically loads the ActiveDirectory module, but it cannot connect. I get an error that resource URI was not found in the WS-Management catalog.

This also brings up another strange thing; I don't understand why I can't connect to the resource URI's that are listed in the remote Powershell. If I do a PS_GetSessionConfiguration, I see the following:

ADExchange (my own custom)
Microsoft.Powershell
Microsoft.Powershell.Workflow
Microsoft.Powershell32
Microsoft.ServerManager

However, I cannot connect to any of those. When I setup my connection information object, I have to use the following URI:

```
string shell = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange";
```

All other URI fail. Why is that?

Anyway, here's some code:

```
using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo))
            {

                runspace.Open();

                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = runspace;

                    Pipeline pipe = runspace.CreatePipeline();

                    ps.Commands.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddArgument("ActiveDirectory");
                    ps.Invoke();

                    ps.Commands.AddCommand(CreateNewUserCommand());
                    ps.Commands.AddCommand(CreateAddGroupCommand("FacnStaff"));
                    //ps.Commands.AddCommand(CreateAddGroupCommand("AllFacStaff"));
                    //ps.Commands.AddCommand(CreateAddGroupCommand("PasswordManagerFacStaff"));

                    results = ps.Invoke();
                }
            }
```

The first command, CreateNewUserCommand, does an "New-Mailbox". This works in isolation, if I comment out the other commands.

The other commands all do some variation of this:

```
  private Command CreateAddGroupCommand(string group)
        {
            var command = new Command("Add-ADGroupMember");
            command.Parameters.Add("Identity", group);
            command.Parameters.Add("Members", _username);

            return command;
        }
```

So my problems:

1) I cannot run AD Powershell Commands Remotely
2) I cannot load the ActiveDirectory module remotely
3) I cannot connect to different Powershell shell configurations

Please help

Answer (score 0):

All they symptoms point to the remote shell being restricted to NoLanguage mode.  This is normal for Exchange remote sessions.  The only thing you can execute in that session is the Exchange cmdlets. No other cmdlets or even basic language elements are available (you can't even create a variable).

Shay Levy wrote an article describing you to re-configure those sessions for Full Language mode to get around these restrictions.

[get-full-control-over-your-exchange-remote-powershell-session](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/scriptfanatic/2011/08/22/get-full-control-over-your-exchange-remote-powershell-session/)